# Question regarding diameter of subsets of a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces

The question is :

Find a condition on a metric space$(X,d)$ that ensures that there exist subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ with $A \subset B$ such that $diam(A)$ = $diam(B)$.

I know that if $X$ is a metric space and $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ with $A \subset B$ then

$diam(A)$ <= $diam(B)$.

If i assume that the metric $d$ on $X$ is the discrete metric then then diameters of $A$ and $B$ will be the same.

Is this good enough ? or can there be some other condition on the metric space $X$ ?

Comment: HINT:

>A: [0, 1]

>B: [-1, 0, 1].

Yes you only need the discrete metric. Why are you trying to overcomplicate it?

Comment: Reading the question literally, he just wants a sufficient condition. For example, "$(X,d)$ is the Euclidean plane$ is such a condition. Reading between the lines, maybe a more interesting condition is wanted; maybe the *most general* condition is wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you need is that $X$ has at least one point. If $A=\emptyset$ and $B$ is a one-point set, then $A\subset B$ and $diam(A)=diam(B)=0$.

A commenter has claimed that $diam(\emptyset)$ is undefined. I quote from Kuratowski's *Topology* Volume I, 1966 edition, p. 207:

> **III. Diameter. Continuity. Oscillation.** The *diameter*, $\delta(X)$, of a set $X$ is the least upper bound of the distances of its points. If $\delta(X)$ is finite, the set X is said to be *bounded*.
> The following propositions are easily proved:$$\{\delta(X)=0\}\equiv\{X\;is\;empty\;or\;is\;composed\;of\;a\;single\;point\};\;\;\;(1)$$

Comment: @user103402 I think you mean sup $\emptyset=-\infty$; it is generally accepted that inf $\emptyset=+\infty$, and besides the diameter of a set is defined as a supremum, not an infimum. However, it is the supremum in the complete lattice $[0,\infty]$, not in $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the condition you want is extremely natural. The converse is really rare.
If $A$ is allowed to be empty, then the condition is just that $X$ is non-empty, as $diam(\{x\})=0=diam(\emptyset)$.

If you require $A$ to be non-empty, then the condition is $|X|\geq 3$. Indeed, let $B=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ consist of three points, then $diam(B)=max\{d(x_i,x_j)\}$. Choose $A$ to be the set consisting of the two points maximising the distance.